# IOS : How to Copy One User Define Model Class to Another Object of It's type

Tags: iphone, ios, object

## i have a problem in Coping a Object

I created a Model Class and use the Object Where i required it.
Certainly i required a copy of it for Some Reason

so i use in the following manner

```
 Modeldata *copyOfDate=[[[Modeldata alloc]init ]autorelease];
 copyOfDate=[g_Data copy];//This Line Gives me a Exception .
```

i think i need to OVERRIDE the copy Method and assignment Operator.

Please provide Me a solution for it, i am waiting for the Quick Response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override `copyWithZone` method in your model class implementation as follows.

```
@implementation Modeldata

-(id) copyWithZone: (NSZone *) zone
{
     Modeldata *objModeldata = [[Modeldata allocWithZone:zone] init];
     objModeldata.yourProperty = yourProperty;
     objModeldata.yourProperty1 = yourProperty1; //All your properties
     return objModeldata;
}

@end
```

Now if you do following will work

```
Modeldata *copyOfDate=[g_Data copy];
```

You don't need to allocate memory there by writing

```
Modeldata *copyOfDate=[[[Modeldata alloc]init ]autorelease];
```